# Showing an analytic function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function whose real part is strictly positive. Prove or disprove $f$ is constant.

My attempt:
Define $g(z)=exp(f(z))$ for all $z$ $\in \mathbb C$ then $|g(z)|=exp(Re(f(z))>1$. Then $g(z)\neq0$ for all $z\in \mathbb C$ . Then $\frac{1}{g(z)}$ is also an entire function and $\frac{1}{|g(z)|}<1$ . Then by Liouville's theorem $g$ is constant. Taking the derivative of $g$ we get $f'=0$ . Hence $f$ is constant.
Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, your proof is fine!